# How to check if $array = array(1) { [""]=> NULL } is true or false

Tags: php, arrays

I have an addon with the case that an array gets on `var_dump($array)` :

```
array(1) { [""]=> NULL }
```

How can i check if this is true or false? 
If the array is set it will get e.g.

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(2) "test" }
```

I tried

```
if ($array == NULL)
if ($array[""] == NULL)
if ($array[""] == "NULL")
if ($array == "NULL")
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: if ((count($array) == 1) && !$array[""])

Comment: What do you mean *check if it's true or false*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"" as array-index is a little bit scary ...

Since $array[0] as first element won't work, you could try this to figure out if the array nodes are null:

```
$fillCount = 0;
foreach ($arrData as $key => $value)
{
    if (!is_null($value)) $fillCount++;
}

if ($fillCount <= 0)
{
    // nothing useful in the array
}
else
{
    // useful content in the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean check if the value is null or not you can use the empty:

```
if(empty($array[""]))
       //element is null
else
       //element is not null
```

the array for sure is not null, since it has one element( array(1) )

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(is_null($array[""]));
```